# How to access file data in memory after a block read in C++

Tags: c++, memory, memcpy

I am having a very difficult time with this block of code: Ubuntu OS and g++

```
 is.open(name.c_str(),ios::in | std::ifstream::binary); }
while (!is) ; // this is the end of the user input loop, asking for "name"
// get length of file:
is.seekg (0, is.end);
int length = is.tellg();
is.seekg (0, is.beg);
// allocate memory:
char * buffer = new char [length];
// read data as a block:
is.read (buffer,length);
is.close();
```

This code works and the whole file is properly displayed on my terminal. The problem comes up when I try to do anything else with the file data. I've managed this, starting from the above:

```
is.close();
std::cout.write (buffer,length);
char x;
int i;
char *it = buffer;
char *ip;
std::cout << "\nbuffer contains: \n\n";
ip = it;
//  for ( i = 0 ; 10  ; ++i ) {
//  std::cout << &ip << "\n";
//  ip++ ; }
std::cout << &ip << "\n";
*ip++ ;
std::cout << &ip << "\n";
*ip++ ;
std::cout << &ip << "\n";
ip++ ;
std::cout << &ip << "\n";
std::cout << "\n";
```

I used this,  cout << "buffer is: " << typeid(*buffer).name() << '\n'; which gave buffer is: c. Also, the for loop is commented out because it doesn't ever quit. The first 8 characters of the file are: (define , including the space) The single statements in the code above give  0x7fffa7119610 repeated 4 times.

I need to search the file data multiple times, character by character. What should I do to make that possible? And if I try memcpy into an array of characters, how do I create the array of the right size?

Comment: The data is already in `buffer`, so the code you posted doesn't show us what you say is going wrong.

Comment: Two things: 1) The code example you posted is garbled. What is " }
while (!is) ;" supposed to be about?  2) Explain what you mean by the statement "the file data seems to be stored as long integer." What does that mean?  Actually, there's a third confusing part about your question: "When I try to address anything to output using read". "Read" generally refers to reading input, not producing output. Please rewrite your question and clarify it.

Comment: Please show the code that is not working as expected.  Also, what makes you think that “the file data seems to be stored as long integer”?  It is `char`s.  What we really need to help you is a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) The `for` loop doesn't quit because you have given it no reason to quit. Your condition (the middle part, between the two semicolons) is just a constant `10`: in the world of C / C++ that is always **true** (because it is not `0`) so the loop never quits. You need something like

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

if you want a loop to run 10 times.

2) You get the same value printed 4 times because that is what asked it to print! `ip` is a pointer: you have incremented **the value it points at** in your expression `*ip++` (last time round you do manage to update the pointer, once): and you have printed **the address of the pointer** (**NOT** the address of the value it points at, or the value contained there) by passing `&ip` to `cout`.